# Compute GCP values for gdal_translate in a PNG image

Tags: georeferencing, gdal-translate

I am using the incorrect GDP for gdal_translate based on gdlainfo command line since image is offset from correct location.  Image is at correct location when I use QGis GeoReference using my clicked on corners which are not the same as I used when using the command line gdal_translate.  How do I translate the GCP corners to the correct values??  I need to automate my georeferencing.

**Command Line Call:**

gdalinfo --> Upper Left  (0.0, 0.0) Lower Left  (0.0,10434.0) Upper Right (11242.0,0.0) Lower Right (11242.0,10434.0) Center ( 5621.0, 5217.0)

gdal_translate -of GTiff  -gcp 0  10434 43.0 11.0 -gcp  11242  10434 44.0 11.0 -gcp 0 0  43.0 12.0 -gcp  11242 0  44.0 12.0 myimage.png myimage.tif

gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 myimage.tif myimage_2.tif

**QGis Call that Works:**

gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 1001.19 202.821 43 12 -gcp 10826.7 180.285 44 12 -gcp 978.659 9983.29 43 11 -gcp 10826.7 10028.4 44 11 myimage.png myimage_2.png

gdalwarp -r near -tps -co COMPRESS=NONE  myimage_2.png myimage.tif

Answer (score 2):

My png image had white space around the edges which caused my GCP offset problem.  A full answer to plotting a "density" map and generating tiles can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185554/generate-density-plot-of-big-data-set-to-overlay-in-google-maps